# spark round function result

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

spark version 3.1.3

```
        Dataset<Row> dataset = loadSource();  // Can be ignored
        dataset = dataset.withColumn("a", lit(1));  // Can be ignored
        dataset = dataset.withColumn("round", functions.round(lit(1).divide(lit(3)), 8)); // ①
        dataset = dataset.withColumn("round2", functions.round(lit(1).cast(DataTypes.createDecimalType(35, 10)).divide(lit(3).cast(DataTypes.createDecimalType(35, 10))), 8)); // ②

        dataset.explain(true);
        dataset.show();
```

result

| round | round2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0.33333333 | 0.333333 |

I expected round2 to be 0.33333333 as well。

The difference between round and round2 is that round2 casts 1 and 3 to DataTypes.createDecimalType(35,10). The following is the relevant plan

```
round((cast(1 as double) / cast(3 as double)), 8) AS round


    round(CheckOverflow((promote_precision(cast(cast(1 as decimal(35,10)) as decimal(35,10))) / promote_precision(cast(cast(3 as decimal(35,10)) as decimal(35,10)))), DecimalType(38,6), true), 8) AS round2
```

My guess is that spark will go to checkOverflow.  If it exceeds decimal(35,6), then just keep 6 decimal places。

If that's the case, I'd like to know if I can turn off this optimization behavior

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting config `spark.sql.decimalOperations.allowPrecisionLoss` to false? (I'd be interested myself to see what happens ;))

Comment: @mazaneicha 
````spark.sql.decimalOperations.allowPrecisionLoss = false ````
 I tried it and it solved my problem. I see the official website has the following paragraph explaining。[it doesn’t adjust the needed scale to represent the values and it returns NULL if an exact representation of the value is not possible.] I need to check if it fits our business. Thanks